# What's your favorite folding method (or secret techique) in Vim for HTML, Javascript and CSS?

Tags: vim, fold

I use something like this: `1,40 fo` but I think is not the most efficient way.

What's yours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use `foldmethod=marker` and have mappings to enter `<!-- {{{ -->` and `<!-- }}} -->` where I want the fold to start and end. I put the start marker on the line with the opening block tag like:

```
<div id="topmenu"> <!-- {{{ -->
```

so when it's folded I immediately see what the fold contains without the need to add extra comment.

For CSS it's even easier, I just use `foldmarker={,}` and all definitions are automagically folded showing me just a very clear list of all classes, tags and ids which I can open just when I need them. Actually all my CSS files have this line at the very end:

```
/* vim: set fdm=marker fmr={,}: */
```

You can also visually select the region you want to fold and press `zf` if you prefer.

Comment: That's sounds good, how did you set different foldmarkers for both HTML and CSS?

Comment: Foldmarkers are different as I keep HTML and CSS strictly in separate files.

Comment: /* vim: set fdm=marker fmr={,}: */ <---this calls Vim's folding method just for the individual CSS file with this line?

Comment: Yes, it's called `modeline`, it's a way to set specific Vim options for any file. `:help modeline`

Comment: So what do your co-workers think of you littering code with markers? :(

Answer (score 6):

I flip between indent and marker with this in my vimrc..

```
let g:FoldMethod = 0
map <leader>ff :call ToggleFold()<cr>
fun! ToggleFold()
    if g:FoldMethod == 0
        exe 'set foldmethod=indent'
        let g:FoldMethod = 1
    else
        exe 'set foldmethod=marker'
        let g:FoldMethod = 0
    endif
endfun
```

Indent works ok for most beautified html but I use marker for large declarative table of contents style folding of documents. Depending on who wrote the file, one will work better than the other so you need quick access to both.

Comment: You could do that without the global variable by checking `if &foldmethod == 'marker'` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Best folding method for vim for html: [use haml instead](http://haml-lang.com/). Best option for css: [use sass instead](http://sass-lang.com/).

I'm actually serious. They make it much more compact.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but good ideas. Out of curiosity, what is the syntax highlighting and folding support like in Vim for SASS and HAML?

Comment: Hey HAML and SASS look great! Is there a lot of people using them?

Comment: It unfortunately won't solve the problem of editing files written by other authors though.

Comment: @Jay: re syntax highlighting / folding in vim, the support is excellent. You can perfectly fold using `foldmethod=indent`, because the structure is *defined* by the indent. @janoChen: lots of people are indeed using HAML and SASS. There's no particular disadvantage, either - since they generate pretty html/css, you can always drop back to html if you like. @michael, there are also conversion scripts from html / css.

Comment: @Jay: Tim Pope maintains excellent syntax highlighting for HAML and SASS here: http://github.com/tpope/vim-haml

Comment: Kind of a trolling answer :-P

Answer (score 1):

I have used `foldmethod=ignore` almost exclusively.  However, my desire to have ignored lines default to the *higher* fold level of the above or below lines, instead of the lower, inspired the following:

```
" Default foldmethod
" Similar to fdm=indent, but lets blank and comment lines default high.
set fen fdm=expr fdi=
set foldexpr=EswaldFoldLevel(v:lnum)

function! EswaldFoldLevel(lnum)
  let ignored = '^\s*\([#/*]\|$\)'
  if getline(a:lnum) !~ ignored
    " In the general case, just use the indent level.
    " It would be nice if it didn't skip several levels...
    return indent(a:lnum) / &sw
  endif

  let previndent = 0
  let prevnum = a:lnum - 1
  while prevnum > 0
    if getline(prevnum) =~ ignored
      let prevnum = prevnum - 1
    else
      let previndent = indent(prevnum) / &sw
      break
    endif
  endwhile

  let nextindent = 0
  let maxline = line('$')
  let nextnum = a:lnum + 1
  while nextnum <= maxline
    if getline(nextnum) =~ ignored
      let nextnum = nextnum + 1
    else
      let nextindent = indent(nextnum) / &sw
      break
    endif
  endwhile

  return max([previndent, nextindent])
endfunction
```

(Sorry about the syntax highlighting...)

I use that as a custom plugin, letting individual filetypes override it.  Python, for example, doesn't want to look at previous lines, just following ones.